# Gulp 4.0: gulp-remember or gulp-cache prevent sass to compile properly (Incremental build)

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, incremental-build

yesterday I've upgraded my Gulp to 4.0 in order to gain some speed while compiling styles for my project (they got big, right now on my Mac Pro 2016 I need to wait 19seconds)

After some digging I decided to add gulp-cached and gulp-remember to my build.

Here's my current gulpfile.js for the styles:

```
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
cached = require('gulp-cached'),
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
remember = require('gulp-remember'),
gs = gulp.series,
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
gp = gulp.parallel;

gulp.task('compile:styles', () => {
return gulp.src([

    // Grab your custom scripts
    './assets/scss/**/*.scss'

])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // Start Sourcemaps
    .pipe(cached('sass'))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    }))
    .pipe(remember('sass'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Creates sourcemaps for minified styles
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'));
});

gulp.task('watch:styles', () => {
gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*.scss', gs('styles'))
    .on('change', function (event) {
        console.log("event happened:"+JSON.stringify(event));
        if (event.type === 'deleted') {
            //delete from gulp-remember cache
            remember.forget('sass', event.path);
            //delete from gulp-cached cache
            delete cache.caches['sass'][event.path];
        }
    });
 });

gulp.task('watch', gp(
'watch:styles'
));
```

My issue here is that my build works well on first compilation which takes about 3 seconds, later on where ever I do a change it can see in which file I made that change, and it starting to compile, but the output file does not have the changes inside.

I think I am not getting something when it comes to gulp-cached and gulp-remeber. But at the end of the file you can see a function that are supposed to clean the caches once a change was made.

Can you please take a look at my code? Maybe you will have some advice.

Cheers!

### EDIT 26.08

I have encountered the following post while looking for a solution:
http://blog.reactandbethankful.com/posts/2015/05/01/building-with-gulp-4-part-4-incremental-builds/

I went with it accordingly with the following code (but the effect is same as in above example):

```
// Grab our gulp packages
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
gs = gulp.series,
gp = gulp.parallel,
cache  = require('gulp-memory-cache');

gulp.task('compile:styles', () => {
return gulp.src('./assets/scss/**/*.scss', {since: cache.lastMtime('sass')})
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // Start Sourcemaps
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    }))
    .pipe(cache('sass'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Creates sourcemaps for minified styles
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'));
});

gulp.task('watch:styles', () => {
gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*.scss', gs('compile:styles'))
    .on('change', cache.update('sass'));
});

gulp.task('build', gs(
'compile:styles',
'watch:styles'
));
```

Comment: After more digging I found out that to compilation works if I make a change in my main file that has all the imports, however when I make a change inside imported file nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

I have created a complete **gulpfile.js** here: 
https://gist.github.com/MkBeeCtrl/5a6a0900dba1c5d42dc7b6da211b3e95

With js files compilation included.

```
// Grab our gulp packages
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
gs = gulp.series,
gp = gulp.parallel,
cached  = require('gulp-cached'),
dependents = require('gulp-dependents');

gulp.task('compile:styles', () => {
return gulp.src('./assets/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(cached('sass'))
    .pipe(dependents())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // Start Sourcemaps
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions']}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Creates sourcemaps for minified styles
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'));
});

gulp.task('watch:styles', () => {
gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*.scss', gs('compile:styles'))
    .on('change', function (event) {
        console.log("event happened:"+JSON.stringify(event));
        if (event.type === 'deleted') {
            //delete from gulp-remember cache
            //emember.forget('sass', event.path);
            //delete from gulp-cached cache
            delete cache.caches['sass'][event.path];
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('build', gs(
'compile:styles',
'watch:styles'
));
```

The above solution works the way I want, so if you want to produce separate CSS files from multiple imported files, you can go with it. It's not blazing fast solution but I have managed to save about 1 second when recompiling (already saved about 15s, when I started this topic, a build lasted 19 secs):
1st compile: ~3.5s
2nd or late: ~2.4s

You dont need to concate or order here as the whole order thing happens when you import scss files into you main file.

Comment: great progress from 19s down to 2.4s. I would stop there since from now on it seems to be microoptimization.

Comment: what if you try `{since: gulp.lastrun('styles:compile')}` instead of `cached`? It should make the whole thing faster since `cached` reads files.

Comment: I wonder if I can make it faster, while working with dependancies and not concating files you always have to compile to main file with all the imports right?

Comment: I will try it in a sec

Comment: With since I got the following timing (I have disabled autoprefix and sourcemaps for that test):

[13:56:19] Finished 'compile:styles' after 2.17 s
[13:56:19] Starting 'watch:styles'...
event happened:"assets/scss/_custom-styles--adminArea__bottomNav.scss"
[13:56:26] Starting 'compile:styles'...
[13:56:28] Finished 'compile:styles' after 1.53 s

Comment: so, a bit faster?

Comment: and with cached (same here: sourcemaps and autoprefix are disabled) i got the folowing:

[13:58:51] Starting 'compile:styles'...
[13:58:54] Finished 'compile:styles' after 2.46 s
[13:58:54] Starting 'watch:styles'...
event happened:"assets/scss/_custom-styles--adminArea__bottomNav.scss"
[13:59:00] Starting 'compile:styles'...
[13:59:02] Finished 'compile:styles' after 1.57 s

Comment: So in summary when recompiling with cached the differences is tiny, but it is visible on first compilation. 
As you previously said cached is more reliable so in that case what will you choose?

Comment: I would go with cached.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I suppose it might do what you want to achieve:

```
'use strict';
const gulp = require('gulp');
const path = require('path');
const cached = require('gulp-cached');
const remember = require('gulp-remember');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('styles:compile', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/scss/**/*.scss', {since: gulp.lastrun('styles:compile')})
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
        //.pipe(cached('sass')) - a smarter but heavier alternative to since
        .pipe(remember('sass'))
        .pipe(concat('all.sass'))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'));
});

gulp.task('styles:watch', function() {
    var watcher = gulp.watch('assets/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('compile:styles'));
    watcher.on('unlink', function(filepath) {
        remember.forget('sass', path.resolve(filepath));
        //delete cached.caches.sass[path.resolve(filepath)];
    });
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('styles:compile', 'styles:watch'));
```

Install `path` plugin to resolve paths. Use 'unlink' event if you want to detect when a file gets deleted. `since` just checks dates which is faster compared to `cached` that reads and compares content. But `cached` is more reliable (for example, when you deleted and then returned the file using your IDE tools `since` will not work since the file will be returned again with its old date). Also check paths - I might have messed them up.

Comment: looks good, but for now I can't make it work due to order issues, I have the order maintained in 3 separate files that are compiled from over 40 .scss files. I wonder if gulp-order can do the work, however manual ordering files sounds preety painful :D

Comment: Do you mean that it compiles but your 40+ scss files get included in random /wrong order and styles on the page are broken?

Comment: Yeap, you are correct, but it's not even able to finish compiling due to missing $variables. Tried to use gulp-order but for now it didnt do a trick...

Comment: Right now going through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554099/gulp-only-compile-changed-files-and-compile-parents-when-imported-scss-file-is 
as this may be a missing puzzle

Comment: Also try a smart trick from here: https://discourse.roots.io/t/ordering-stylesheets-before-gulp-concat/3489 That guy suggests adding prefixes to your files so that make them appear in the right order.

Comment: Solution from here looks so easy: https://blog.thecodecampus.de/speed-up-your-less-build-with-gulp/ and almost identical, how they make it work, huh? Crazy...